# How do I fetch only entered characters on textbox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In my project, I use a textbox to send a string to a serial port device. I also show the data from the serial port device on the same textbox. When sending data to the device I only need to send the values ​​entered from the keyboard.In short, how do I distinguish between characters entered from the keyboard and data on the textbox?

(I can say that I am trying to make a command client like cmd. The only thing I want is to be able to send and receive data from the serial port device via the same textbox.)

Answer (score 0):

Just remember the number of characters you have received/ sent so far. Then you can just call String.Substring (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring) and send the "new" characters only.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I have a situation like this. The device sends data continuously and the number of characters changes frequently. Wouldn't that be a problem?